# Why does np.linalg.eig produce an opposite-signed eigenvector?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, numpy, linear-algebra

I am learning [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) by following this [MIT course](https://youtu.be/Yw1xmxPH_ps?t=431).  In this video, the lecturer is finding the SVD for

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 5 \\ -1 & 7 \end{pmatrix},
$$

which involves finding the eigenvalues for

$$
C^T C = 
\begin{pmatrix}
26 & 18 \\ 18 & 74
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

In the example (at the time in the link above), the lecturer finds eigenvalues

$$\begin{pmatrix}-3/\sqrt{10} \\ 1/\sqrt{10} \end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt{10} \\ 3/\sqrt{10} \end{pmatrix}.$$

But `np.linalg.eig` produces the opposite vector to the second one:

```
w, v = np.linalg.eig(C.T*C)
v
matrix([[-0.9486833 , -0.31622777],
        [ 0.31622777, -0.9486833 ]])
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector.  LAPACK (which np.linalg.eig uses under the hood) chooses to return unit-length eigenvectors (good for SVD!), but this still leaves two choices, and there doesn't seem to be a convention for which one to return; it's up to the underlying algorithm (which in turn may depend on the input data).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998228/sign-of-eigenvectors-change-depending-on-specification-of-the-symmetric-argument

Comment: thanks for your answer. would you please point out which rule apples for this specific case?

Comment: I've had a quick look, but can't see it yet.  numpy is calling `_umath_linalg.eig` ( https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1311 ), which seems to in turn use one of the *geev.  As the answer in my SO link says, from there you'd need to understand the FORTRAN code underlying _that_ function, and that's deeper than I want to dig for this.

Comment: thanks for your reply! what does "*geev" mean?

Comment: I was trying to reference the different drivers LAPACK uses for solving variants of the eigenproblem; having known about ones named dgeev and zgeev, and having seen somewhere "_geev", I was just trying to indicate the family.  As it turns out, there are a lot more: 
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node32.html#tabdriveseig